# Set runtimepath, adding a directory from an expression in vim?

Tags: bash, runtime, vim

Inn `~/script.vim`, I have:

```
set runtimepath+=string(substitute(expand("%:p"), 'script\.vim', '', 'g'))
```

I have an alias in `.bashrc`:

```
alias vimscript="vim -S ~/script.vim"
```

Running `string(substitute(expand("%:p"), 'script\.vim', '', 'g'))` works as intended.

The problem is when using it in the set runtimepath expression, it doesn't work when I call `vimscript` in terminal which calls `script.vim`. When I run `set rtp` in vim after being called by vimscript to check the runtimepath, the desired appended string isn't showed (but the other ones are there).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have some additions to @Laurence Gonsalves answer:

1. There is also «concat and assign» operator: `.=`, so

   ```
   let foo=foo.bar
   ```

   can be rewritten as

   ```
   let foo.=bar
   ```
2. Code

   ```
   let &runtimepath.=','.string(path)
   ```

   will append `,'/some/path'` to &runtimepath, while you probably need `,/some/path`.
3. I guess that you want to append path to your script to runtimepath. If it is true, then your code should be written as

   ```
   let &runtimepath.=','.escape(expand('<sfile>:p:h'), '\,')
   ```

   inside a script, or

   ```
   let &runtimepath.=','.escape(expand('%:p:h'), '\,')
   ```

   from current editing session (assuming that you are editing your script in the current buffer).

Comment: your approach is better IMO, using substitute was indeed ugly when it's possible to use expand parameters. Thanks.

Comment: Or if you already saved a path into a variable, e.g. `let dein_path = <my-path>`, then you can simply set the runtime path with `let &runtimepath.=','..dein_path` (dotdot stands for concat).

Answer (score 5):

The right hand site of a `set` command is not an expression, it's a literal string.

You can manipulate options (the things `set` sets) by using `let` and prefixing the option name with an `&`. eg:

```
let &runtimepath=substitute(expand("%:p"), 'script\.vim', '', 'g')
```

To append to `runtimepath` with a `let` you can do something like:

```
let &runtimepath=&runtimepath . ',' . substitute(expand("%:p"), 'script\.vim', '', 'g')
```

(The `.` is the string concatenation operator.)

Comment: I think I need to read all vim documentation, and some books to understand all this concepts. I tried the second option, but still doesn't work: now, instead of string(substitute(expand( I have '' when I run set rtp. What am I missing?

Comment: @Somebody The expression you had included `string()`, which it shouldn't have. (I'd just copied your expression verbatim into the right pattern.) I've updated the answer to use the corrected form of your expression. It could probably still be simplified, as ZyX has done, but this should at least get you on the right track.

Comment: @Somebody BTW, I've never read a vim book. `:help` in vim is actually quite good, but there are a *lot* of nooks and crannies. I've been using Vim for well over a decade and I still learn new stuff about it on a regular basis.

Comment: Removing the script wasn't working. I think it was a setup issue. I've updated my question with more information. Thanks anyway, +1!

Comment: @Somebody Your updated questiopn shows another problem, which is that you're using `expand()` incorrectly. You're using `%` which expands to the buffer's filename, but you want `<sfile>`. Also, where are you putting this line, in `script.vim` or in your vimrc? It won't work in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

by 2022 i used this:

```
if ( isdirectory($some_shell_variable)  )
    set runtimepath+=$vi
endif
```

You can use a plain vim variable or whatever else just as well.